# vim-autoformat plugin - undefined shiftwidth function

Tags: error, plugin-vim-autoformat

I'm getting undefined shiftwidth function error when I try to run `Autoformat html` in vim-autoformat plugin.

AFAIU shiftwidth is a variable, not a function.

Checking plugin's source I see that it invokes it by a certain "s" object:

```
let g:formatdef_astyle_cs = '"astyle --mode=cs --style=ansi --indent-namespaces -pcH".(&expandtab ? "s".shiftwidth() : "t")'
```

which I couln't find. Anyone knows how I solve this ?

My VIM version: 7.3.429

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shiftwidth() is a function that has been added I think late in the 7.3 circle. Can you update your Vim version?

Comment: I updated the question with my VIM version. And will try to update to 7.4.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira From [`:help fixed-7.4`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/version7.txt.html#fixed%2d7%2e4): "Patch 7.3.694 [..] Add the shiftwidth() function". So yeah, you need  a newer Vim version (path 7.3.694 or higher).

Comment: 7.4 is compiled against a different ruby version. when installed breaks my command-t plugin. I'll try to update to a higher 7.3 branch.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira It sounds to me that fixing Command-T is the way to go, rather than stick with an old version forever ;-)

Comment: Coporate desktop. Some things are linked to other things. Updating ruby version is not an option.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Okay, that can be difficult :-) You can try using the work-around described in [`:help shiftwidth()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#shiftwidth%28%29) btw. I see this plugin doesn't have many updates, so modifying it locally is probably okay.

Comment: I tried... I putted it in a .vim file the .vim/plugin folder and it didn't work. In the plugin's file where it calls it, also didn't work. where do I put this workaround code ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Use the function from :h shiftwidth(), put it into the plugin file and make sure to have the quoted line above call your modified function.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira alternatively, replace every shiftwidth() function call by the shiftwidth option, e.g. this part: ` "s".shiftwidth()` by `"s".&sw` should also work (needs to be done everywhere).

Comment: when I substitued by "s".&sw it finally worked. Thanks